# This patent looks to be a spam/troll attempt

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement, novelty, us20100313926

In reference to the patent: [US20100313926](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100313926)

I'm an electrical engineering major that just graduated with my masters degree. I was looking at zeolite applications and I stumbled onto this patent. After reading through it, I'm having a hard time believing that it is legit. After much word-smithing, there is nothing actually "accomplished" or "claimed" aside from.... well everything honestly. The wording of the application shows the person claiming it might not understand Peltier/Seebeck modules clearly. Also, under the claims it grabs at almost any possible combination of heat absorbing material or heat releasing material.

In y'alls opinion, does this seem like a patent troll to you? It just doesn't sit right with me.

Comment: You can go to http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair to see a history of the application. The examiner requested the applicant to elect a specie because claim 5~12 refer to five distinct and independent species. The applicant never responded and the application was deemed abandoned on 2012-07

Comment: Oh I didn't know that! Neat!